# Automatically remove parts of a C# file

Tags: c#

I have a code generation tool that creates a single cs file with some interfaces, classes and a namepsace (with other classes in it). Some of the classes are defined outside of the namespace. What I would like to do is automatically strip away the namespace (and everything in it) and one of the classes (along with its associated attributes).

I know I could potentially write a regex expression to do this but I'm hoping there is some tool that understands the layout of the CS file (as a tree) so I can tell it which parts I want to prune away.

Comment: You're looking for Roslyn.

Comment: That would be https://roslyn.codeplex.com/